# R - Multiple plot with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this small dataset

```
map red_team blue_team
 1     7         8
 2     21        32
 3     11        22
 4     10        8
```

And I am trying to create a multiplot where each individual plot one represents one of the maps (1,2,3 and 4), and the content is two bars, one for red_team and another for blue_team on the X axis and the score on the Y axis.

This what I currently have.

```
ggplot(winners_and_score, aes(red_team)) + geom_bar() + facet_wrap(~ map)
```

I'm having issue trying to display the score for both teams.

[image: Current plot]

Thanks.

Comment: `reshape2::melt(winners_and_score, id = "map")` will give you a long format data.frame making this easier

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require(reshape2)
require(ggplot2)

# toy data
df = data.frame(map = 1:4, red_team = sample(7:21, 4, replace=T), 
                               blue_team = sample(8:32, 4, replace=T))

df.melted <- melt(df, id='map')

> df.melted
  map  variable value
1   1  red_team     8
2   2  red_team    15
3   3  red_team    17
4   4  red_team    19
5   1 blue_team    22
6   2 blue_team    32
7   3 blue_team    31
8   4 blue_team    18

# making the plot
ggplot(data=df.melted, aes(x=variable, y=value, fill=variable)) + 
       geom_bar(stat='identity') + 
       facet_wrap(~map) + 
       theme_bw()
```

[image]